# Destroying instance of my counter when changing view using router in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm using a vue-router in my vue application. In one of my components, I have got a simple counter inside the requestAnimationFrame. But every time I am changing from Page2 (where the counter is) to Page1 and back to Page2 I seem to get a new instance of my counter. How can I solve so my last counter is totally removed when I swap the pages? Illustrating the problem with the image below:

[image]

and after entering Page 2 twice

[image: nter]

as you can see, two number sequences counting upwards

I also tried to delete the instance of debugInc but getting:

```
this.debugInc.destroy is not a function
```

My code is below and in the repo here:
https://github.com/reppoper/forumpost

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link to="/">Page1</router-link> | 
    <router-link to="/page2">Page2</router-link> 
     <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  }
}
</script>
```

**Helloworld.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
}
</script>
```

**Goodbyeworld.vue  (where the counter is)**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>GOODBYE</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",

  data: function () {
    return {
      debugInc: 0,
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.loop();
  },

  methods: {
    loop() {
      requestAnimationFrame(this.loop);
      console.log(this.debugInc);
      this.debugInc = this.debugInc + 1;

      if (this.debugInc > 59) {
        this.debugInc = 0;
      }
    },
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    console.log("DESTROY");
    this.debugInc.destroy();
  },
};
</script>
```

My views:

**Page1.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <HelloWorld/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "../components/HelloWorld.vue";
export default {
    components: {
        HelloWorld
    }
}
</script>
```

**Page2.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <GoodbyeWorld />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import GoodbyeWorld from "../components/GoodbyeWorld.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    GoodbyeWorld,
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

requestAnimationFrame returns the ID of the request as an integer value. You have to store this ID and when the vue component is destroyed you should call cancelAnimationFrame with the same ID.

```
export default {
name: "HelloWorld",

data: function () {
    return {
        debugInc: 0,
        id: null,
    };
},

created() {
    this.loop();
},

methods: {
    loop() {
        this.id = requestAnimationFrame(this.loop);
        console.log(this.debugInc);
        this.debugInc = this.debugInc + 1;

        if (this.debugInc > 59) {
            this.debugInc = 0;
        }
    },
},
beforeDestroy() {
    console.log("DESTROY");
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.id);
},
```

};